# Parsing double quotes in Databricks Spark

Tags: csv, apache-spark, databricks, double-quotes

I have a .csv file with rows containing string values:

```
"315700H9VGE9BHU9DK42","""LEGOS s.r.o."", švédsky ""LEGOS bolag med begr.amsvar""","cs","",""
```

My second field occasionally contains  'strings with enclosed "quote" values':

```
"""LEGOS s.r.o."", švédsky ""LEGOS bolag med begr.amsvar"""
```

That when read into a spark dataframe the value would present:

`"LEGOS s.r.o.", švédsky "LEGOS bolag med begr.amsvar"`

I have tried this, and variations of the commented out options as described [in these docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-csv.html)

```
df = (spark
    .read
    .format("csv")
    .option("header", True)
    .option("delimiter", ",")
    .option("multiline", True)
    .option("escapeQuotes", True)
    
    .option("quote", "\"")  
    .option("escape", "\"")

    # .option("escape", "\\")
    # .option("escape", '""') 
    # .option("escape", "\n")

    .schema(raw_schema)
    .csv(landing_schema_file)
     )
```

Any ideas?

I'm running on Apache Spark 3.3.0, Scala 2.12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think I have nailed the problem down as something to do with how Databricks and Spark process that data, rather than reading it.

I am reading a large 3GB .csv file into Databricks using. As per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45138591/4538066) and the answer by @vilabinot:

```
df = (spark
    .read
    .format("csv")
    .option("header", True)
    .option("inferSchema", True)
    .option("multiline", True)
    .option("escape", "\"")
    .csv(file_path_or_directory)
     )
```

One of the fields in this dataset is Country code. To test if the file read was OK, groupby and aggregate on this:

```
df.groupby("Country").agg(count("*").alias("count"))
```

Which is where erroneous values were being returned i.e. non-Country codes are returned as groups.

| Country | count |
| --- | --- |
| PL-10 | 1 |
| 1 TO 10, AFFIL TOWER, L. H. ROAD, | 1 |

But, If I then try to filter the df to these values:

```
display(df.filter(col('Country') == "PL-10"))
```

Nothing is returned. So I think this is in fact something to do with the way that Spark or Databricks is trying to optimise different functions, rather than the data read step itself. A few other tests I tried which replicate this behaviour on groupby and filter were:

- reading from json version of the data
- splitting the .csv into smaller files e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75305183/read-multiple-csv-files-with-different-number-of-columns-for-each-csv-file)

For reference, the dataset is the GLEIF LEI index.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `.csv` file which contains only this row:

```
"315700H9VGE9BHU9DK42","""LEGOS s.r.o."", švédsky ""LEGOS bolag med begr.amsvar""","cs","",""
```

And you want to return:

```
+--------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+---+----+----+
|_c0                 |_c1                                                  |_c2|_c3 |_c4 |
+--------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+---+----+----+
|315700H9VGE9BHU9DK42|"LEGOS s.r.o.", švédsky "LEGOS bolag med begr.amsvar"|cs |null|null|
+--------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+---+----+----+
```

You can use:

```scala
spark.read.option("escape", "\"").csv(yourPath)
```

I hope this answers your question, good luck!

Comment: What I end up with is: 

_c0 = 315700H9VGE9BHU9DK42
_c1 = """LEGOS s.r.o.""
_c2 =  švédsky ""LEGOS bolag med begr.amsvar"""

I used .option("escape", "\"") in my original example too. It fails to parse the quotes within quotes